# C++primer 5ed 1.23 and the example in 1.4.4 have different output

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++

This is the code in 1.4.4

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    int currval=0,val=0;
    if(std::cin>>currval){
        int cnt=1;
        while(std::cin>>val){
            if(val==currval){
                ++cnt;
            }   
            else{
            std::cout<<currval<<" occurs "
            <<cnt<<" times "<<std::endl;
            currval = val;
            cnt=1;
            }
        }
        std::cout<<currval<<" occurs "
        <<cnt<<" times "<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

This the code in practice 1.23

```
#include<iostream>
#include"Sales_item.hpp"
int main()
{
    Sales_item curbok;
    Sales_item bok;
    if(std::cin>>curbok)
    {
        int cnt=1;
        while(std::cin>>bok)
        {
            if (bok.isbn() == curbok.isbn())
            {
                ++cnt;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout<<"Total selling of "
                <<curbok.isbn()<<" is "<<cnt
                <<std::endl; 
                curbok = bok; 
                cnt = 1;              
            }
        }
        std::cout<<"Total selling of"
        <<curbok.isbn()<<" is "<<cnt<<std::endl; 
        std::cout<<"222"<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I think they have similar process to achieve the function.
But in the first code:

1. Type number 1 1 1 2 2 2
2. Type Ctrl+Z
3. Output the answer

   ```
   1 occurs 3 times 
   2 occurs 3 times
   ```

In the second code

1. Type 202-x 2 2, 202-x 2 2, 203 - x 2 2
2. Type Ctrl+Z and press enter
3. Output the answer

```
Total selling of 202-x is 2
```

4. Type Ctrl+z again and press enter
5. Output the remained answer

```
Total selling of 203-x is 1
```

Why does the second code require typing Ctrl+Z two times to end the stream

I run the code in VScode and MinGW-x64 g++ in Windows10 system

The Sales_item.hpp included in the 1.23 code:

```
#ifndef SALESITEM_H
// we're here only if SALESITEM_H has not yet been defined 
#define SALESITEM_H

#include "Version_test.hpp" 

// Definition of Sales_item class and related functions goes here
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Sales_item {
// these declarations are explained section 7.2.1, p. 270 
// and in chapter 14, pages 557, 558, 561
friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Sales_item&);
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Sales_item&);
friend bool operator<(const Sales_item&, const Sales_item&);
friend bool 
operator==(const Sales_item&, const Sales_item&);
public:
    // constructors are explained in section 7.1.4, pages 262 - 265
    // default constructor needed to initialize members of built-in type
#if defined(IN_CLASS_INITS) && defined(DEFAULT_FCNS)
    Sales_item() = default;
#else
    Sales_item(): units_sold(0), revenue(0.0) { }
#endif
    Sales_item(const std::string &book):
              bookNo(book), units_sold(0), revenue(0.0) { }
    Sales_item(std::istream &is) { is >> *this; }
public:
    // operations on Sales_item objects
    // member binary operator: left-hand operand bound to implicit this pointer
    Sales_item& operator+=(const Sales_item&);
    
    // operations on Sales_item objects
    std::string isbn() const { return bookNo; }
    double avg_price() const;
// private members as before
private:
    std::string bookNo;      // implicitly initialized to the empty string
#ifdef IN_CLASS_INITS
    unsigned units_sold = 0; // explicitly initialized
    double revenue = 0.0;
#else
    unsigned units_sold;  
    double revenue;       
#endif
};

// used in chapter 10
inline
bool compareIsbn(const Sales_item &lhs, const Sales_item &rhs) 
{ return lhs.isbn() == rhs.isbn(); }

// nonmember binary operator: must declare a parameter for each operand
Sales_item operator+(const Sales_item&, const Sales_item&);

inline bool 
operator==(const Sales_item &lhs, const Sales_item &rhs)
{
    // must be made a friend of Sales_item
    return lhs.units_sold == rhs.units_sold &&
           lhs.revenue == rhs.revenue &&
           lhs.isbn() == rhs.isbn();
}

inline bool 
operator!=(const Sales_item &lhs, const Sales_item &rhs)
{
    return !(lhs == rhs); // != defined in terms of operator==
}

// assumes that both objects refer to the same ISBN
Sales_item& Sales_item::operator+=(const Sales_item& rhs) 
{
    units_sold += rhs.units_sold; 
    revenue += rhs.revenue; 
    return *this;
}

// assumes that both objects refer to the same ISBN
Sales_item 
operator+(const Sales_item& lhs, const Sales_item& rhs) 
{
    Sales_item ret(lhs);  // copy (|lhs|) into a local object that we'll return
    ret += rhs;           // add in the contents of (|rhs|) 
    return ret;           // return (|ret|) by value
}

std::istream& 
operator>>(std::istream& in, Sales_item& s)
{
    double price;
    in >> s.bookNo >> s.units_sold >> price;
    // check that the inputs succeeded
    if (in)
        s.revenue = s.units_sold * price;
    else 
        s = Sales_item();  // input failed: reset object to default state
    return in;
}

std::ostream& 
operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Sales_item& s)
{
    out << s.isbn() << " " << s.units_sold << " "
        << s.revenue << " " << s.avg_price();
    return out;
}

double Sales_item::avg_price() const
{
    if (units_sold) 
        return revenue/units_sold; 
    else 
        return 0;
}
#endif
```

Comment: The "1.4.4" code appears to accept only integer input. Therefore, the alleged input "Type 202-x", for "the second code", does not match the expected input. Your question is unclear.

Comment: I made the code wrong.I have edited the question again

Comment: do you have the spaces in the input `203 - x 2 2` ? When a string is read from the stream via `>>` you only get `203` then reading a number fails, ie the condition for  `while(std::cin>>bok)` would be `false` and the program should terminate without needing to press Ctrl-z

Comment: No.203-x is considered as a string to be read.And every object of type Sales_item allows us to input one string and two number(maybe) in turn